# Does an Irish citizen need a visa for a week's tourist visit to America?

Tags: visas, usa, irish-citizens

If an Irish citizen travels from Ireland to America as a tourist, for a week, do they need a visa?

Comment: If you are an Irish Citizen, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_Waiver_Program - that should answer your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [Visa Waiver Program](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html) "allows citizens of participating countries* to travel to the United States without a visa for stays of 90 days or less".

(Ireland IS a participating country).

Each traveller must have authorisation under [ESTA](http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/visit/visa-waiver-program.html#ESTA).

It costs US$14, and the [US Embassy in Dublin](http://dublin.usembassy.gov/general/esta.html) has all the information you would require.

It takes up to 3 days to process, is valid for 2 years, and you need to have it approved before you leave for the US.  It's all done online. ( - and is fairly simple - I've done it twice before, myself)